# self.window in NativeScript

Tags: ios, appdelegate, nativescript

I have a pod that requires this in the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions... and I have no idea what to do :/

```
    // Your UI setup logic (if not using storyboards)
    self.window = ...
    self.window.rootViewController = ...
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    instance.presentOnboardingUIOnWindowCompletionHandler(self.window, function(args){
      //Complete Callback        
    })
```

Clearly {N} doesn't use storyboards, so what would I do here?

**EDIT**
Okay so this seems to work, but it kinda takes over the entire screen, and the app is DOA when the window hits the completion handler.  I think what I need to do here is find the main original root window and make that key and visible, but...?

```
    var myWindow = new UIWindow();

    myWindow.makeKeyAndVisible();

    instance.presentOnboardingUIOnWindowCompletionHandler(myWindow, function(args){
        resolve({
            window: myWindow,
            args: args    
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add handler to `application.launchEvent`. This event is raised in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` so there you will have access to the `OSApplication` instance. From there you could access our `UIWindow` using `_window` field. I don't recommended access private field but we haven't expose it yet.
Please note that this window is not made keyAndVisible yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this in the app.js file. Something like this perhaps:

```
var application = require("application");

if (application.ios) {
    var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
        for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        __.prototype = b.prototype;
        d.prototype = new __();
    };

    var appDelegate = (function (_super) {
       __extends(appDelegate, _super);
       function appDelegate() {
           _super.apply(this, arguments);
       }

       appDelegate.prototype.applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions = function (application, launchOptions) {
            // Do your magic here...
       };

       appDelegate.ObjCProtocols = [UIApplicationDelegate];
       return appDelegate;
    })(UIResponder);
   application.ios.delegate = appDelegate;
}
```

Comment: I have that method already, is the root UIWindow available in the args somewhere there?  I'm just not seeing it to use it...